# error in echoing out div with angularjs directive

Tags: php, angularjs

so i need to do something that based on user's session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
$text = "<section>
        <table>
          <tr data-ng-repeat=\"msg in msgs\"
          data-ng-click=\"function($event, ms,'lalalala')\"
              <td>blablabla</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      </section>";

echo $text;
}
```

The code above keep resulting error with

```
Undefined variable: event
```

Is there anything wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is probably trying to replace $event

```
$text = "<section>
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat=\"msg in msgs\"
      data-ng-click=\"function(".'$event'.", ms,'lalalala')\"
          <td>blablabla</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </section>";
```

Ideally really you want to just have your templating done client side and a clear separation between the API and the client.

Comment: @Foster there are a couple of reasons I'd say not to write into the view from the service layer.  1 it makes debugging problems more complicated instead of testing/debugging an API and independently building/testing the views you are doing both at once. 2 if you decide to consume the data with some other client (native iOS, Android, and/or desktop app) then you have to parse HTML instead of a JSON response which is easily consumable.  3 if you decide to change the server side code it's going to affect the client.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code - php tries to evaluate what is within double quotes, and you have what looks like a variable inside (*$event*)

```
         data-ng-click=\"function($event, ms,'lalalala')\"
```

Use single quotes if you don't want php to try and evaluate the string. See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

```
$text = '<section>
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="msg in msgs"
      data-ng-click="function($event, ms,\'lalalala\')"
          <td>blablabla</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </section>';
```

Comment: data-ng-click='function($event, ms,'lalalala')'. do you mean like that sir? it is still not working

Comment: No, the entire php String that you set to the variable $text (in this case, no need to escape the double quotes inside)